# Handle null exception in linq to xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
var qXML = (from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
            where nm.Element("Status").Value.Contains(status) && int.Parse(nm.Element("Empersonal_Id").Value) == ele.EmpId
            select nm).SingleOrDefault();
```

Above is my sample code. Now there are instances where `ele.EmpId` will be present in the xml and instance where it will not be. How do i handle the null exception that is thrown when `ele.EmpId` is not found.

Comment: @restless? uh? ele is present, when i query the xml for ele, it may not be in it.. i need to handle that scenario

Comment: Why is the question being voted down, isn't it a valid question?

Comment: Even though I am not the down-voter, but it is probably voted down because you are not active enough to consider using your thoughts a bit. SO, is to help you solve a problem, not for providing you free code samples.

Answer (score 0):

This checks both if the element is `null` and the element contains a non empty/null string value, and will short circuit if it fails either of those checks, before it tries to parse.

```
var qXML = (from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
            where nm.Element("Status").Value.Contains(status) && 
            ((nm.Element("Empersonal_Id") != null) && 
             !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nm.Element("Empersonal_Id").Value) &&
             int.Parse(nm.Element("Empersonal_Id").Value) == ele.EmpId)
            select nm).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Value should already be of type string, and even if null it will not raise a NullReferenceException, which is most likely caused by referencing the Value property of a non existing element.